# date/time-picker and file upload (image) fields for custom fields (e.g. with more fields)

Tags: plugins, media-library, date-time, datepicker, customization

I got used working with the [More Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/more-fields/) plugin. But it seems that fields like

- datepicker
- timepicker
- date/timepicker
- image upload (media library)

are missing somehow. Is there a plugin which can do that?

I already found [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) together with the [Date and Time Picker Field Addon](http://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-field-date-time-picker/) or [Simple Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-fields/). But both seems to have issues with the latest versions.

More Fields has a file upload feature but it should be possible to upload images in the media library to prevent duplicate content.

The last option which comes to my mind is using the WYSIWYG editor together with text input fields (for date and time, for picture URL from media library).

Are there some easier solutions for the editor?